# Select 100 random lines from a file with a 1 million which can`t be read into memory

Tags: java, algorithm, file, inputstream

Actually, this question was asked one of the interviews, I do not know the exact answer, could you explain in detail ?

> How would you select 100 random lines from a file with a 1 million
>   lines? Can`t read file into memory.

Comment: Did you mean from a file with 1 million lines?

Comment: yep, thats what I mean

Comment: Is the length of each line constant?

Comment: Is it important that each line has exactly the same probability of being chosen?

Comment: Does it make any difference?

Comment: @GökhanAkduğan If the line length is constant, you can just pick a number [0-999999] and search to number*line length immediately.

Comment: Actually, this was a question to gauge the knowledge how to handle the things which are not fit into memory.

Comment: @GökhanAkduğan I think that is understood, my preference it to use memory mapped files. That way you can access them at random and let the OS worry about how much is in memory (assuming you have an OS which supports this such as Unix or MacOSX)  On Windows, you have to explicitly read only the bits you need.

Comment: See Knuth, TAoCP Vol 2, Algorithm 3.4.2 S.  I suspect the question might have been intended to see if you were aware of Knuth and the algorithms he presents.

Answer (score 4):

Typically, in such scenarios, you **do not know** the number of items in the input file in advance (and you want to avoid requiring two passes over your data, to check the number of available items first). In that case the solution proposed by @radoh and others, where you will create indices to select from, will not work.

In such cases, you can use [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling): You only need to know the number of items you want to select (`k` as follows) and you iterate over the input data (`S[1..n]`). Below is the pseudocode taken from Wikipedia, I'll leave it to your practice to convert this into a working Java method (the method would typically look something like `List<X> sample(Stream<X> data, int k)`):

```
/*
  S has items to sample, R will contain the result
*/
ReservoirSample(S[1..n], R[1..k])
  // fill the reservoir array
  for i = 1 to k
      R[i] := S[i]

  // replace elements with gradually decreasing probability
  for i = k+1 to n
    j := random(1, i)   // important: inclusive range
    if j <= k
        R[j] := S[i]
```

Note that although the code mentions `n` explicitly (i.e. the number of input items), you do not need to know that value prior to computation. You can simply iterate over an `Iterator` or `Stream` (representing lines from a file in your case) and only need to keep the result array or collection `R` in memory. You can even sample a *continuous* stream, and at each point in time (at least, as soon, as you've seen `k` samples) you have `k` randomly chosen items.

Comment: I believe reservoir sampling will only select duplicates if there are duplicates in the data. This has nothing to do with k being close to n.

Comment: Typically you touch the data more than once. For example, once you have run reservoir sampling on it once you have (or could have) the count. But still it is a nice and useful sampling technique (even though it is not using all the parameters of the interview question.)

Comment: You're right about the duplicates, I'll fix this, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Generate the 100 random (unique) numbers (ranging from 0..1000000-1) into a list and then go through the file reading the lines with indexes from the list. Ideally, the list of numbers should be a `Set`.

Pseudocode:

```
int i = 0;
List<String> myLines = new ArrayList();
while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
  String line = fileScanner.nextLine();  
  if (myRandomNumbers.contains(i)) {
    myLines.add(line);
  }
  i++;
}
```

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung can you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, I missed a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty efficient way to do it:

```
Iterator<String> linesIter = ...
List<String> selectedLines = new ArrayList();
Random rng = new Random(seed);

int linesStillNeeded = 100;
int linesRemaining = 1000000;

while (linesStillNeeded > 0) {
  String line = linesIter.next();
  linesRemaining--;
  if (rng.nextInt(linesRemaining) < linesStillNeeded) {
    selectedLines.add(line);
    linesStillNeeded--;
  }
}
```

I haven't coded in Java in a while, so you might want to treat this as pseudo-code.

This algorithm is based on the fact that the probability that any given line (assuming we are uniformly selecting k distinct lines out of a total of n lines) will be contained in the collection with probability k/n. This follows from

1) the number collections of k distinct lines (out of n lines) is choose(n, k),

2) the number of collections of k distinct lines (out of n lines) which contain a particular line is choose(n-1, k-1), and

3) choose(n-1,k-1)/choose(n,k) = k/n

Note that k and n here correspond to `linesStillNeeded` and `linesStillRemaining` in the code respectively.